# Creating configurable product programmatically

Tags: php, magento, import, magento-1.5

I'm trying to create configurable products programmatically in Magento 1.5.1.
I understand I need first to create simple related products, **what I did**. Now I manage to associate these simple products to make a configurable one.

Here is the critical part...
I keep the ids and some of the attributes values in an array, so I can later make my configurable product, but some of them are missing, I don't know which method to call.
I found [this entry](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/46844/) in Magento Wiki, that helped me and seems to fit my needs.
However, at the end the author is setting two things :

```
$product->setConfigurableProductsData($data);
$product->setConfigurableAttributesData($data);
```

and the values in the arrays have been taken in the admin page source using Firebug....and then translated into PHP arrays (array example for the first call) :

> "I’ve harcoded the values for my associated products and attribute
>   data.  You can get attribute data by viewing the source through the
>   admin interface and using Firebug for Firefox."

```
$data = array('5791'=>array('0'=>array('attribute_id'=>'491', // I already got this
                                       'label'=>'vhs',        // this too
                                       'value_index'=>'5',    // but what is value_index ?
                                       'is_percent'=>0,
                                       'pricing_value'=>'')),
              '5792'=>array('0'=>array('attribute_id'=>'491',
                                       'label'=>'dvd',
                                       'value_index'=>'6',
                                       'is_percent'=>0,
                                       'pricing_value'=>'')));
```

My question is : is there a way to retrieve these values without using Firebug (which in my script won't help me a lot !), but programmatically.  I already found a way to retrieve attribute values, labels, etc... using its code, but one field I don't know is `value_index`.
I guess this may be the option position in an option list, but not sure.
Also if someone knows a good/better way to create a configurable product in Magento, please tell me.
Any help is welcome thank you.

Comment: Which author on the wiki page? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I'm talking about the second post on the page, by juice1492..

Comment: The pedant in me wants to point out that the linked page is not a wiki entry, it's a forum thread. I feel guilty for even raising this point.

Comment: @clockworkgeek - don't feel guilty. Yeah a forum thread.. but you surely know, what is 'value_index' and how to retrieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're asking where to retrieve the `value_index` value where you already have the `label`.  Here's what I had:  I didn't test this on 1.5x.

```
function get_attribute_id($option, $type) {
   $attributeId      = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $type);
   $attribute        = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
   $attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

   foreach ($attributeOptions as $opts_arr) {
       if (strtoupper($opts_arr['label']) == strtoupper($option)) {
          return $opts_arr['value'];
       }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

$value_index = get_attribute_id('vhs', 'media_format');
```

No one else seemed to mention the easiest way to figure out what the `value_index` of vhs is:  In the backend, under 
`Catalog` > `Manage` > `media_format` > `Manage Label/Options`
Inspect the source of the individual form inputs.  Where you have 'vhs' you should have an input named `option[value][6]`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, there are two options: a) create simple products by script, put the generated id's in an array and create the configurables using the ids or b) read the id's from the admin and put them in your script. Since programming is about automation I'd definately go for option a.

Comment: yes I need this to write an product update script, but how to retrieve the values found in the admin page source ? once again, in my script there are no such things...are there good methods I can call to get them ?

Comment: I won't find that information in simple product data... I'm looking for a solution to find  what the author grabbed with Firebug. I think it's related to attributes...

Comment: Then you have to load the product first. If you do $data = $simple->getData() you will get basic data like db id. If you want all data, you have to load the product: $data = $simple->load($simple->getId())->getData();

Comment: no you don't understand, I don't need the product data at all (not more data of a **simple** product). My need is to retrieve **attribute** data in order to create a **configurable** product and link my **simple** product to... telling Magento programmatically which attributes to use for.